# Django filter with ForeignKey not working

Tags: python, django

I am building ecommerce and having trouble creating dashboard for sellers. No matter how I try to get filter processed orders so I can show sold products to sellers I couldn't make it happen. Some help will be a great relief. Following is my Seller Mixin I am trying to create:

mixins.py

```
class SellerAccountMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, object):
        account = None
        products = []
        transactions = []
        orders = []
        def get_account(self):
            user = self.request.user
            accounts = SellerAccount.objects.filter(user=user)
            if accounts.exists() and accounts.count() == 1:
                self.account = accounts.first()
                return accounts.first()
            return None

        def get_products(self):
            account = self.get_account()
            products = Product.objects.filter(seller=account)
            self.products = products
            return products

        def get_all_products(self):
            account = self.get_account()
            products = Product.objects.all()
            self.products = products
            return products
        def get_sold_products(self):
            orders = UserCheckout.objects.get(user_user=self.user)
            return orders
```

seller/views.py:

```
class SellerDashboard(SellerAccountMixin, FormMixin, View):
    form_class = NewSellerForm
    success_url = "/seller/"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.user
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        apply_form = self.get_form() #NewSellerForm()
        account = self.get_account()
        exists = account
        active = None
        context = {}
        if exists:
            active = account.active
        if not exists and not active:
            context["title"] = "Apply for Account"
            context["apply_form"] = apply_form
        elif exists and not active:
            context["title"] = "Account Pending"
        elif exists and active:
            context["title"] = "Dashboard"
            #products = Product.objects.filter(seller=account)
            context["products"] = self.get_products()
            context["today_sales"] = self.get_today_sales()
            context["sold_products"] = self.get_sold_products()
            #context["total_profit"] = self.get_total_profit()

        else:
            pass

        return render(request, "sellers/dashboard.html", context)
```

Above is my seller app and I am bringing the products model with simple features. The problem is that its not letting me get processed orders with UserCheckout model in Orders app. Following is a snapshot of Orders app.

Orders/models.

```
class UserCheckout(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email


ADDRESS_TYPE = (
    ('billing', 'Billing'),
    ('shipping', 'Shipping'),
)

class UserAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserCheckout)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=ADDRESS_TYPE)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.street

    def get_address(self):
        return "%s, %s, %s, %s" %(self.street, self.city, self.state, self.zipcode)


CHOICES = (
    ('CreditCard', "CreditCard"),
    ('Cash On Delivery', 'Cash On Delivery'),
    ('PayPal', 'PayPal'),
)


ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES={
    ('created','Created'),
    ('paid','Paid'),
}

class Order(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES, default='created')
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserCheckout, null=True)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(UserAddress, related_name='billing_address', null=True)
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(UserAddress, related_name='shipping_address', null=True)
    shipping_total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, default=5.99)
    user_seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    order_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=2, )
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    paymethod = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=CHOICES, default='CreditCard')
    seller = models.ForeignKey(SellerAccount, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.cart.id)
```

I can get multiple products but I need to filter products by seller and orders by seller. After trying multiple times I always get stuck with error:

```
user has to be a UserCheckout instance:

User "Admin": Must be a "User" instance.
```

and

```
'SellerDashboard' object has no attribute 'user'
```

1. I need to filter products by seller.
2. I need filter orders with paid status by the seller.

Seller Account Model:

```
class SellerAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="manager_sellers", blank=True)
    #orders = models.ManyToManyField(Order)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("products:vendor_detail", kwargs={"vendor_name": self.user.username})
```

I am stuck so bad that I don't have courage to continue with django anymore. Please help.

Comment: show your `SellerAccount` model

Comment: and show your queries explicitly that are failing

Comment: Added SellerAccount above. I am trying queries again as I haven't saved queries I tried. Please bare with me

Comment: As per my mixins.py in sellers app, if I try to get orders same way in function get_products by user....I get all the products but can't get all the orders. However "seller" foreignkey is added in both Product model as well as in Order model. Can't figure it out.